# How to use "blit" in matplotlib to write a program that can use "drag" movement to see different part of image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use matplotlib to write a program that after zooming an image displaying on the plt.figure object, when I do a mouse "click and drag" movement, the displaying part will move toward my dragging direction so I can see different part of the zooming image by using setting x/y limit.

I know the easiest way is to use canvas.draw() function after reset the x/y limit, like this

```
ax.set_xlim([x1,x2])
ax.set_ylim([y1,y2])
ax.figure.canvas.draw()
```

But in my formal program, there will be not only image on the figure, but also lots of other objects such as text or line, and if I use canvas.draw(), it will redraw everything including those objects that are not change at all and will seriously damage the performance of the program. In order to consume the least resource to do the dragging function, I decide to use "blit" function, here is my toy example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class toy(object):
 def dragstart(self, event):
    # 'button_press_event'

    if not event.inaxes:
        return
    if event.button == 1:
        self.dragstate = 'move'
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        self.mouseloc = [x, y]


 def dragstop(self, event):
    # 'button_release_event'
    if event.button == 1:
        self.dragstate = 'stop'


 def drag(self, event):
    #Prevent multiple event happening
    if self.dragprocessing:
        return
    self.dragprocessing = True


    if not event.inaxes or self.dragstate != 'move':

        self.dragprocessing = False
        return


    #Calculate the displacement
    xloc, yloc = event.xdata, event.ydata
    xdelta = -(xloc - self.mouseloc[0])
    ydelta = -(yloc - self.mouseloc[1])
    self.mouseloc = [xloc, yloc]

    newxleft = self.last[0] + xdelta
    newxright = self.last[1] + xdelta
    newyup = self.last[2] + ydelta
    newydown = self.last[3] + ydelta

    #Border check
    if newxright > self.limit[0] - 0.5:
        over = newxright - (self.limit[0] - 0.5)
        newxright = self.limit[0] - 0.5
        newxleft -= over

    if newxleft < -0.5:
        over = -0.5 - newxleft
        newxleft = -0.5
        newxright += over


    if newydown > self.limit[1] - 0.5:
        over = newydown - (self.limit[1] - 0.5)
        newydown = self.limit[1] - 0.5
        newyup -= over

    if newyup < -0.5:
        over = -0.5 - newyup
        newyup = -0.5
        newydown += over
    newposition = [newxleft, newxright, newyup, newydown]


    #Set new limit
    self.ax.set_xlim([newxleft, newxright])
    self. ax.set_ylim([newydown, newyup])


    #Only draw the changing part
    #The formal project contents lots of other objects such as text or line, redraw everything will be slow
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.ax.images[0])
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.ax.yaxis)
    self.ax.draw_artist(self.ax.xaxis)
    self.ax.figure.canvas.blit()


    self.last = newposition
    self.mouseloc = [xloc + xdelta, yloc + ydelta]
    self.dragprocessing = False

  def __call__(self, images):


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(images)
    h = images.shape[0]
    w = images.shape[1]
    self.limit = [w, h]
    ax.set_ylim([400, 200])#just an example
    ax.set_xlim([200, 400])#just an example

    self.dragprocessing = False
    self.last = [200, 400, 200, 400]#present x/y limit
    self.dragstate = 'stop'

    self.ax=ax
    self.fig=fig
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.dragstart)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_release_event', self.dragstop)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', self.drag)

    plt.show()


 imagenow = plt.imread("path/to/my/image")
 test=toy()
 test(imagenow)
```

Note that I use "self.ax.figure.canvas.blit()" instead of "self.ax.figure.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)" because the latter will update nothing on the axis.
The problem is, the stick of x/y axis will overlay each time the x/y limit is updated, like this
[image: Example of dragging "up"]

Is there any misuse in my toy example of "blit" that causing the problem? How to fix it or is there any better way to do the job?

Comment: You need to understand what *blitting* means: It will draw the respective artist inside a given rectangle, anything inside that rectangle will just be overplotted. So if there are other lines inside the region of interest, they would need be redrawn as well, leading to the situation that you would need to redraw everything.. in which case you could also just call `draw()`.

Comment: So it means that it doesn't have a concept like "layer" in some image editing program which i can only modify some part of the displaying image without affecting other part; every time I do some modification, blitting will directly put it on top of any other object, so the best solution is I still need to redraw everything once the displaying image change?

Comment: It would be useful if you have a static background and want to repaint something on top. But here the image should probably be in the background? So everything else needs to be repainted as well.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help